# How is the name of this feature?

Tags: asp.net

I wanna have, when a user clicks an button, the screen should go black and in the middle should be a new webpage.

I know this is very often used for Images, but I know it is possible with webpages too.

How is the name of this feature and how I can get it for my asp.net page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit has the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) control,

Or can use many jquery plugins ([ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) for example).

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about a "Lightbox" effect ?

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts